# Recyclerview dynamically load more data using stackFromEnd

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-recyclerview

Hey guys I'm using an recycler view for a chat application which needs to be a bit different than regular infinity scrolls. I want to load more data while scrolling up. I found a lot of stuff here but nothing could help with my problem. I'm using an SQLCipher db and want to load more (older) chat items only if the user scrolls up.

So what I want to do:

1. I want to load for example 20 Items which I'm doing here:

   ```
   ArrayList<Message> getNextMessages(String ChatID, int alreadyLoadedMessages) {
   ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();

   String[] args = {ChatID};

   Cursor cursor = database.query(MessageDBHelper.DATABASE_NAME,
           columns, MessageDBHelper.COLUMN_USER_ID + "=?", args, null, null, null);

   cursor.moveToLast();
   int loaded = alreadyLoadedMessages;
   while (loaded > 0 && !cursor.isBeforeFirst()) {
       cursor.moveToPrevious();
       loaded--;
   }
   while (!cursor.isBeforeFirst() && loaded <= LOADED_ITEMS) {
       messageList.add(0, cursorToMassage(cursor));
       cursor.moveToPrevious();
       loaded++;
   }
   //notify scrollview that we are finished with data loading
   Chat.loading = false;
   return messageList;
   }
   ```
2. I want to listen on Scrolls and if there e.g. only 10 elements left I will start to load new data so there will be no loading screen:

   ```
   messageArrayList.addAll(messageDataSource.getNextMessages(KontaktNummer, currentLoadedItems));
   currentLoadedItems = currentLoadedItems + MessageDataSource.LOADED_ITEMS;
   layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
   layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   final RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapterChat(this, messageArrayList);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
       @Override
       public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
           super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
           int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
           int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
           int pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
           int sumn = visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems;
           if (!loading) {
               if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) < 10) {
                   loading = true;
                   messageArrayList.addAll(0, messageDataSource.getNextMessages(KontaktNummer, currentLoadedItems));
                   currentLoadedItems = currentLoadedItems + MessageDataSource.LOADED_ITEMS;
                   //TODO:notify adpater

               }
           }
       }

   });
   ```

So what isn't working:

1. for test purposes i added 5000 messages in my chat so last messages are 5000, 4999,4998,...
   for some reason my recyclerview jumpps every time to '4980' if new data is insert
2. data is not propperly loaded, sometimes there are 'walls' where nothing happens

I already found stuff like that: [Android Recyclerview load more on scrolltop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994472/android-recyclerview-load-more-on-scrolltop/37002222) but nothing could help me.

I appreciate your time and advices!